# Why does my column not exist in Google Sheets? Query error

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I'm trying to run a simple query to condense a list of information from a column (which contains a consistent data type), removing blanks. I have the following code:

```
=query({Z:Z},"select * WHERE NOT Z =''")
```

This produces the error: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Z.

I've encountered similar issues with query elsewhere - for some reason not yet figured out by my brain, my columns somehow don't exist. I've tried using col26, col1, and everything between col1 and col30, to no avail. While I could workaround this particular simple situation with more of a filter() function, I'd like to better understand why my column's aren't computing. I'd appreciate any clarification on this.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
=query({Z:Z},"select * WHERE Col1 is not null")
```

When using curly brackets `{}` instead of normal ones `()` you can not use the column letters any more but the number of the column.

*Example: When you have `=query({D1:F10},"select * WHERE Col3 is not null")` it means `F` is not  null (`D`=`Col1`, `E`=`Col2`, `F`=`Col3`)*

Answer (score 0):

you can either use:

```
=QUERY({Z:Z}, "where Col1 !=''")
```

or:

```
=QUERY(Z:Z, "where Z !=''")
```